# How to read specific words from a file?

Tags: c, data-structures

I have a file that contains words and their synonyms each on a separate line.
I am writing this code that should read the file line by line then display it starting from the second word which is the synonym.
I used the variable count in the first loop in order to be able to count the number of synonyms of each word because the number of synonyms differs from one to another. Moreover I used the condition synonyms[i]==','  because each synonym is separate by a comma.
The purpose of me writing such code is to put them in a binary search tree in order to have a full dictionary.
The code doesn't contain any error yet it is not working.
I have tried to each the loop but that didn't work too.

Sample input from the file:

```
abruptly - dead, short, suddenly
acquittance - release
adder - common, vipera
```

Sample expected output:

```
dead short suddenly
acquittance realse 
common vipera
```

Here is the code:

```
void LoadFile(FILE *fp){
    int count; 
    int i;
    char synonyms[50]; 
    char word[50];
    while(fgets(synonyms,50,fp)!=NULL){
        for (i=0;i<strlen(synonyms);i++)
    if (synonyms[i]==',' || synonyms[i]=='\n')
        count++;
    }
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s",word)==1){
    for(i=1;i<strlen(synonyms);i++){
        ( fscanf(fp,"%s",synonyms)==1);
            printf("%s",synonyms);
        }
      }
    }
    int main(){
    char fn[]="C:/Users/CLICK ONCE/Desktop/Semester 4/i2206/Project/Synonyms.txt";
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(fn,"rt");
    if (fp==NULL){
        printf("Cannot open this file");
    }
        else{
           LoadFile(fp);
        }
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please show sample input.

Comment: @Yunnosch adder - common, vipera

Comment: ... which we asked for [the last time you posted this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67833753/there-is-no-errors-in-the-code-but-it-is-not-working). The comment that said, "...including all necessary code **and precise input data needed to reproduce the problem**. "

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. That should include complete code that can be copied, pasted, compiled, and run with no changes (not necessarily your complete program, but a complete program that demonstrates the problem), input that reproduces the problem, an exact copy of observed output, and a sample of the output you desire instead.

Comment: Please **correctly** add sample data having more than one sample. Correctly means format it as code.

Comment: And while you are at [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67834554/edit) your question, please fix the code indentation.

Comment: `while(fgets(synonyms,50,fp)!=NULL)` followed by `while(fscanf(fp,"%s",word)==1)` without an intervening rewind makes no sense.  You've already read all the data.  The fscanfs have nothing to read.

Comment: It is not a good idea to mix `fscanf` and `fgets`.

Comment: Although it is increasingly common to see useless error messages, that does not make acceptable.  `"Cannot open this file"` is a useless error message.  `perror(fn)`

Comment: Using a hyphen (minus sign) as separator is a bad idea because of hyphenated compound words (Like *seventy-two*). Use for example semicolon instead.

Comment: I am obliged to separate between the word and its synonyms by -

Comment: Is there a way that I can insert the words in the file inyo a binary search tree without using my code at the beginning?

Comment: Using hypen as separator while make the code much more complex if hyphenated compound words must be allowed. The code has to check if there is a space before the hyphen.

Comment: "The code doesn't contain any error" Hard to believe, seeing the compiler errors I get when I try to compile that code, even after adding the more obvious missing things. You really need to make a [mre] of the code which you are talking about, because the shown code is not it. Ideally an MRE should be useable when pasted e.g. here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php, with the provided sample input pasted into the STDIN there. When you did that let me know. Because when I reworked your code to fit that, it worked perfectly, no problems. So, the MRE needs to be by you instead.

Comment: You could also help by explaining in more detail "it is not working".

Comment: I meant that I am getting no output at all yet the compiler is giving me zero errors.

Comment: The compiler isn't giving you any error?!  Your code contains the text `{
         fscanf(fp,"%s",synonyms)==1);`.  There are clearly unbalanced parentheses there. If the compiler is not complaining, then that's not the code you're giving it.

Comment: The calls to `fscanf` make absolutely no sense.  You read a full line of text into a buffer (maybe you do, the code doesn't actually check to see if a full line is read, but let's ignore that issue for the moment), and you seem to be relying on the length of that line while you read from the next line.  Why?  I'm nearly certain that you intend to be doing `sscanf` on the line instead of reading more data.  I don't think you understand how `fscanf` works.

Comment: What is the logic for this output: `acquittance release` for a line with a single synonym?

Comment: I am trying to use this output as nodes in a binary search tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest conceptual misunderstanding demonstrated in the code is a failure to understand how `fgets` and `fscanf` work.

Consider the following lines of code:

```
while(fgets(synonyms,50,fp)!=NULL){
    ...
    while(fscanf(fp,"%49s",word)==1){
        for(i=1;i<strlen(synonyms);i++){
            fscanf(fp,"%49s",synonyms);
            printf("%s",synonyms);
        }
    }
}
```

The `fgets` reads one line of the input.  (Unless there is an input line that is greater than 49 characters long (48 + a newline), in which case `fgets` will only read the first 49 characters.  The code should check for that condition and handle it.)  The next `fscanf` then reads a word from the *next* line of input.  The first line is effectively being discarded!  If the input is formatted as expected, the 2nd `scanf` will read a single `-` into `synonyms`.  This makes `strlen(synonyms)` evaluate to 1, so the `for` loop terminates.  The `while scanf` loop then reads another word, and since `synonyms` still contains a string of length 1, the `for` loop is never entered.  `while scanf` then proceeds to read the rest of the file.  The next call to `fgets` returns NULL (since the `fscanf` loop has read to the end of the file) so the `while/fgets` loop terminates after 1 iteration.

I believe the intention was for the `scanfs` inside the `while/fgets` to operate on the line read by `fgets`.  To do that, all the `fscanf` calls should be replaced by `sscanf`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I have split the work into functions for readability. The actual parsing is done in `parse`function. That function thakes into account hyphenated compound words such as *seventy-two*. The word and his synonyms must be separated by an hyphen preceded by at least one space.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Trim leading and trailing space characters.
// Warning: string is modified
char* trim(char* s) {
    char* p = s;
    int l = strlen(p);

    while (isspace(p[l - 1])) p[--l] = 0;
    while (*p && isspace(*p)) ++p, --l;

    memmove(s, p, l + 1);
    return s;
} 

// Warning: string is modified
int parse(char* line)
{
    char* token;
    char* p;
    char* word;

    if (line == NULL) {
        printf("Missing input line\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // first find the word delimiter: an hyphen preceded by a space
    p = line;
    while (1) {
        p = strchr(p, '-');
        if (p == NULL) {
            printf("Missing hypen\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if ((p > line) && (p[-1] == ' ')) {
            // We found an hyphen preceded by a space
            *p = 0; // Replace by nul character (end of string)
            break;
        }
        p++; // Skip hyphen inside hypheneted word
    }
    word = trim(line);
    printf("%s ", word);

    // Next find synonyms delimited by a coma
    char delim[] = ", ";
    token = strtok(p + 1, delim);
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 1;
}

int LoadFile(FILE* fp)
{
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File not open\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int ret = 1;
    char str[1024];  // Longest allowed line
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp) != NULL) {
        str[strcspn(str, "\r\n")] = 0; // Remove ending \n
        ret &= parse(str);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* fp;
    char* fn = "Synonyms.txt";
    fp = fopen(fn, "rt");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror(fn);
        return 1;
    }
    int ret = LoadFile(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return ret;
}
```